# How to assign full processor(cores/sockets) to a VM? VMware

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, vmware-server

Trying to use VMware. Using Ryzen 9 5950X(16 cores / 32 threads).

The question is how to assign all cores/threads properly to a VM? Were trying different configurations of "Number of Processors" along with "Number of cores per processor". Like 2/16, 16 / 2, 8 / 4 and so on but never got proper value.

Wanna push all, so could use the whole power of CPU in VM :), or at least most.

OC: Windows 10

P.S When I was assing 16 / 1, then in VM i see 2 sockets with 2(or 4) cores via task manager

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to push the whole processor, use the following config:

- Number of processors: 1
- Number of cores per processor: 32

But be aware that, unless you have another processor, it may crash or give you slow performance, since you need some processing power for the main OS. I would recommend using 24-26 cores per processor instead.

Answer (score 0):

VmWare is type 2 hypervisor, which run runs on the host operating system. Type 2 hypervisors can support the maximum of 75% of host hardware. Those hypervisors are type 2 hypervisors: "VmWare, Virtualbox, Parallels, Qemu, ..

Meanwhile type 1 hypervisors, such as "Hyper-v, Microsoft Virtual pc, Windows Sandbox, .. run on the host hardware, so they can use much more hardware than type2 h-vs. So if you plan to use full power of your cpu, i do reccomend using type1 hypervisors, but they have a few disadvantages, such as they rather support Windows Server guest operating systems, and they don't have that much features, such as build in direct vnc connection.

Hope this helped.